# Run function on all pairs of objects in column of data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame with factor "subject", and continuous variables "a" and "b". For each level of subject, I create a distance matrix from a and b:

```
data %>%
group_by(subject) %>%
select(a,b) %>%
do(dmat = as.matrix(dist(.)))
```

This returns an n-by-2 data frame, with subject and dmat as columns. What I would like to do matrix norms of each pairwise subtraction. Something along the lines of:

```
norm(data$dmat[[1]]-data$dmat[[2]])
norm(data$dmat[[1]]-data$dmat[[3]])
# etc etc
```

Ideally, I'd get out an n^2-by-3 data frame, with the first two columns indicating the two subject levels that are being compared, and the third column containing this norm calculation.

Apologies for not providing a sample dataset. I'm hoping the answer is simple enough, but if one is required I will try to write some code to generate one.

Comment: Create a combination of all possible combinations (e.g. `combn(1:3, 2)`) and iterate through that, either using `for` or `apply` family of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapply` for this.

```
data %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  select(a,b) %>%
  do(dmat = as.matrix(dist(.))) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  do(data.frame(s1 = rep(.$subject, each=nrow(.)), 
                s2 = rep(.$subject, times=nrow(.)), 
                dist = mapply(rep(.$dmat, each=nrow(.)), 
                              rep(.$dmat, times=nrow(.)), 
                              FUN=function(x, y) norm(x-y))))
```

I would probably find the matrix representation of this result easier to understand:

```
data %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  select(a,b) %>%
  do(dmat = as.matrix(dist(.))) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  do(data.frame(matrix(mapply(rep(.$dmat, each=nrow(.)), 
                              rep(.$dmat, times=nrow(.)), 
                              FUN=function(x, y) norm(x-y)) , nrow=nrow(.))))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Although the matrix representation is probably easier to understand in the case above, I left a couple factors out for simplicity, and I'm looking at whether distance is greater between-factor than within-factor, so I need to be able to keep the subject IDs encoded.

The "each" vs "times" trick in rep() was the magic for me. Would not have thought of that!